# Horizontally center Bootstrap3 row-fluid container with many nested elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, centering

I've been trying to horizontally center the `.row-fluid` container with many other nested elements, but couldn't find the right way to do that.

Basically, it's the user account page with 4 tabs.

Here's how it looks like now: [codepen.io full page view](http://s.codepen.io/yakovenkodenis/debug/bdPdXQ?)

Also, I need to center the nav tabs, I tried to apply `text-center` to them, but they didn't move.

And for some reason, when I change the nav tab from the first to any other, the whole container moves a little, changes its left margin, is it because of the table inside the first tab?

Here's the [workspace link](http://codepen.io/yakovenkodenis/pen/bdPdXQ?editors=110) where I typed the code.

Could you please help me to horizontally center the whole container and position the navigation tabs in the center of their blue container (`ul` element)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.row-fluid` container appears to be centered. The elements within however are not. You need to change:

```
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 user-details">
```

to this:

```
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 user-details">
```

**Update:** To center the nav links.

CSS:

```
.user-info-block .navigation {
  width: 100%;
  margin:0;
  padding: 18px 0;
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #428BCA;
  border-top: 1px solid #428BCA;
  text-align: center;
}

.navigation li {
  display:inline;
}

.navigation li a {
  padding: 20px 30px;
}
```

Comment: I added `col-md-offset-3` and it become centered, thanks.
Any ideas about centering the nav tabs?

Comment: That's off that 3 column offset is centering. Bootstrap is a 12 column system. 12/3=4 Our middle 4 would need to 4 columns on either side to be centered. The reason you need 3 instead of 4 is that you have overridden the width with your `user-details` class. This will probably introduce further issues if you plan on aligning with the grid. Are you trying to center the nav tabs as well?

Comment: yes, and them too.
By the way, to be honest, I thought I didn't do anything bad when adding `width: 50%`  :(

Comment: @DenisYakovenko I've added the CSS that needs changed for the nav links. Just replace the old rules with those rules. And don't forget to click the checkmark below the number of votes to mark the answer as correct. Thanks!

Comment: Did you notice the small underscore that started to appear on the nav links? why did it happen?

Comment: Add `text-decoration: none;` to your `.navigation li a` rule.